# StaticFileHandler doesn't serve my file

Tags: file, tornado, uglifyjs

I serve with the `StaticFileHandler` a file that come from `uglifyjs`.

If the file is single line, and the output `uglifyjs` is not terminated by an end of line character, it doesn't work:

```
>xxd static/index.js
...
0000010: .... .... .... 3b
```

If I open it and save it with `gedit`, it add a end of line to the file, and `statichandler` works:

```
>xxd static/index.js
...
0000010: .... .... .... 3b0a
```

Is that normal or a bug? What should I do ? Manually add an end-of-line?

Answer (score 0):

StaticFileHandler doesn't care about an end-of-line, so there must be something else going on.  How exactly is it failing?  Are the permissions the same in the two versions of the file?

Comment: Yes, permission are the same.